# Can a Textbox have data validation from a table?

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I'm pretty strong on Excel but new to VBA.
I've built a set of tables and user forms to maintain records of calls, contacts, etc.

This is my question:
Can I use a textbox on a user form for input and editing a table where that specific textbox has data validation from another table in the workbook?

That is, can the data validation list for that textbox be a table field that can add names, etc. to the data validation?

For an example, on the main contact table I have a user form that has a textbox for the person taking the call.
They should be able to pull their name from a list.
I know I could use a combo box but I don't see how to make the combo box data validation dynamic.
Can I use a field in a different table that workbook to be a dynamic range?

Hope that makes sense...
Thanks in advance for any guidance where to look.

Haven't been able to tie a specific table field into the validation thus making it "dynamic".

Answer (score 1):

Set the rowsource for the Listbox on Form initialization.

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim lr As Long
    ListBox1.Clear
    ListBox1.ColumnHeads = True
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If lr > 1 Then
            ListBox1.RowSource = .Range("A2").Resize(lr-1).Address
        End if
    End With
End Sub
```

or alternatively from a table

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ListBox1.Clear
    ListBox1.ColumnHeads = False
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        ListBox1.List = .Range("Table1[[#All],[MYCOLUMN]]").Value2
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm beginning to understand that I should be using a combobox but I'm still missing the way to make one field in a structured table to be the picklist for the validation...

Comment: @cmarzahn see updated alternative. Change Table1 and MYCOLUMN to suit.

Answer (score 0):

Got it...
Works well with a Combobox
Used "intersect" to use only the data in that column...

```vb
Dim myTable As ListObject
Dim myArray As Variant

Set myTable = wksISSInfo.ListObjects("tblISSInfo")
```